# How to use waitFor if we have single store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I am retrieving data through **ajax** request but immediately its not loaded in component, i have to refresh.

```
request.get('/list').end(function (err, res) {
    that.data = res.body;
    if(callback)
        callback(that.data);
    that.emitChange();
});
```

Comment: Where are you making this call? In the store, or through an API action creator? You shouldn't need to use waitFor for a single store but I'll need some more details :)

Comment: thank you ..I used promise() & its done